# google play store in avd

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I have created Xperia_go **AVD** on my latest eclipse indigo with Sony Add-on SDK 1.0 (API level 16) i.e. android 4.1.2

Now I want to install **Google Play Store** on it.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this.

Just use [BlueStacks](http://www.bluestacks.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Simply you can't. The emulator is not intended to use the google play store. There are a few work arounds but you would need a very good knowledge of the ADB console and you would need to get an illegal copy of google play's apk.

If you need to do something using google play then you need to use a physical device.

Answer (score 0):

In Android O, you can install Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image in SDK manager, and it comes with Google Play Store by default.

[image: Google Play Intel x86 Atom System Image]